# Clojure merge multiple map into a single map

Tags: list, dictionary, clojure

I have the following list of maps

```
({"child.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_UNSUBSCRIBE_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}},
  "child.cc.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CC_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_CC_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}}}
  {"child.abusereport" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_ABUSE_RPT"}},
   "child.manualfiltering" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_MANUAL_FILTERING_RPT"}}}
  {"child.assigned.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CREATE_ADVERTISING"}},
   "child.manage.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_LIST_ADVERTISING"}}})
```

I need to have a single map like following.

```
{"child.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_UNSUBSCRIBE_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}}
"child.cc.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CC_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_CC_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}}
"child.abusereport" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_ABUSE_RPT"}}
"child.manualfiltering" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_MANUAL_FILTERING_RPT"}}
"child.assigned.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CREATE_ADVERTISING"}}
"child.manage.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_LIST_ADVERTISING"}}}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: might help to describe the (original) map as : ({"cs" {:roles #{"A" "B" "C"}},
  "c.cc.s" {:roles #{"A" "B"}}}
  {"c.a" {:roles #{"D"}},
   "c.m" {:roles #{"L"}}}
  {"c.a.a" {:roles #{"R"}},
   "c.m.a" {:roles #{"L"}}})

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the "**[into](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/into)**" function, and supply an empty map `{}` as the first argument:

```
(into {} map-list)
```

Here's the output from my REPL session; I copied your code into two vars 'map-list' and 'single-map' (Clojure 1.3.0):

```
(def map-list '({"child.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_UNSUBSCRIBE_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}},
                 "child.cc.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CC_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_CC_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}}}
                {"child.abusereport" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_ABUSE_RPT"}},
                 "child.manualfiltering" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_MANUAL_FILTERING_RPT"}}}
                {"child.assigned.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CREATE_ADVERTISING"}},
                 "child.manage.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_LIST_ADVERTISING"}}}))

#'user/map-list
user=>
(def single-map {"child.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_UNSUBSCRIBE_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}}
                 "child.cc.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CC_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_CC_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}}
                 "child.abusereport" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_ABUSE_RPT"}}
                 "child.manualfiltering" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_MANUAL_FILTERING_RPT"}}
                 "child.assigned.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CREATE_ADVERTISING"}}
                 "child.manage.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_LIST_ADVERTISING"}}})
#'user/single-map

user=>
;; Check to see if we have the desired result
(= (into {} map-list)
   single-map)
true
```

Comment: One caveat - if there exists a key that is in multiple maps, then only its value from the last map will end up in the combined map. If this is not what you want, look at [`merge-with`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/merge-with)

Answer (score 7):

I would probably use `merge` and `apply`

```
(def map-list (list {:a 1, :b 2} {:c 3, :d 4}))
(apply merge map-list) ;; returns {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
(def your-list '({"child.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_UNSUBSCRIBE_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}},
  "child.cc.search" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CC_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION" "ROLE_ADM_CC_VIEW_SUBSCRIPTION"}}}
  {"child.abusereport" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_ABUSE_RPT"}},
   "child.manualfiltering" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_MANUAL_FILTERING_RPT"}}}
  {"child.assigned.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_CREATE_ADVERTISING"}},
   "child.manage.advertisement" {:roles #{"ROLE_ADM_LIST_ADVERTISING"}}}))

(reduce conj your-list)
```

Comment: I think `into` is the more idiomatic way to do this. It's also more efficient than `reduce` since it uses transient collections internally.

Comment: It is true, I believe that this might be slower, but I think it is more intuitive - taken with the above response, this answer helps you to understand that, all the "into" function does, is conjoin its 2nd argument to the first argument.  see (doc into)

Answer (score 0):

This answer clarifies the way that "into" and "conj" interrelate in this instance to both provide acceptable solutions to your problem.  That is, it stands on the shoulders of the previous answers..

You have a list which is of the format :

```
( {key1 value1} 
  {key2 value2} )
```

And you want a map which has extracted the key/value pairs as follows:

```
{key1 value1, key2 value2}
```

The problem, then, is that you essentially want to "conjoin" each successive k/v pair to the last, in a single map.

The 1st solution above does this using into.  If we look at the clojuredoc for into, we see:

> "Returns a new coll consisting of to-coll with all of the items of
>   from-coll conjoined."

The other, similar answer is to use

```
(reduce conj '({key1 value1} {key2 value2}))
```

Clearly, this solution is spelling out the "into" definition above for this problem : the reduce function accumulates each application of the conjoining of the nth + (nth+1th) key value pair, such that it implements the definition for into (at least, for the purposes of this question).