# Replace multiple values in a nested map in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I just spent hours trying to figure this out and even searching for the previous questions but the solutions don't seem to apply so I decided to create a new one.

I have an existing map with certain keys and values that I want to replace with values from another map.

```
(def m '{a {:*x 0 :*velx 1, :*vely 1}})
(def m' '{a {:*velx 9, :*vely 9}})

(assoc (m 'a) (m' 'a))
;; => {a {:*x 0 :*velx 9, :*vely 9}}
```

Since `assoc` needs to take in the content of the map, this doesn't seem to work and I don't know how to 'remove the curly brakets' from it...

Edit: this is different to the suggested existing thread as it's not a list of maps but rather two separate maps and the proposed solution doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clojure merge multiple map into a single map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545778/clojure-merge-multiple-map-into-a-single-map)

Comment: No but it lead me to dig further and I think it works with `(merge-with into m m')` !

Comment: Oh right, i saw it in another thread and thought it's okay for examples. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: No, never.  It is a bug if it ever works at all!

Comment: Using "prime" to describe an successor is quite common in functional programming languages and I have seen it often in books etc about Clojure and use myself from time to time.  Although OT, I'd be interessted, where this actually causes problem given that clojure.core itself uses this pattern for e.g. the big* math operators like `+'`

Comment: @AlanThompson no it's not a bug. It is valid clojure syntax (also, clojure isn't the only lisp allowing this. scheme and racket also do) . The quote has it's special meaning only pereceding some form. Otherwise it is just a char. `(let [jane's-room []] (conj jane's-room :chair))`. though it might not be a good style in most cases, still it is valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find it finally!

```
(merge-with into m m')
=> {a {:*x 0, :*velx 9, :*vely 9}}
```